# How to change path to file in django

Tags: django

I use private storage in django, files are saved in a private path.

In django setting the path to the files:

```
PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT_FILES = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'private/private_files')
```

I declare the file path for the model:

```
##storage for the private files
private_storage_fles = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT_FILES)


And in my Model:
private_file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, storage=private_storage_files)
```

Now i want to copy the project to another computer for testing.
However the files are not found on the new computer because the file paths are different on the new computer.

Sow on computer 1 the saved instance has the following file path: `c:/users/computer1/document/djangoproject/private/file.pdf`
But on computer 2 this path does not exist.
Can i solve this problem?

Comment: So is your problem that you have also transferred the database and stored files and the paths in the database don't match the new file locations, or is it that you can't store new files on the test machine (or both)?

Comment: no the first one, the file path on the new system is wrong because the model instance filefield has the path of the old system